# Why does this while loop never terminate?

Tags: java, while-loop

I am really stuck on understanding this one concept. I had a while loop from one of my exams, and even though I know what prints, I don't know why.

Here is the code:

```
class Test {
    public static void xMethod(int length) {
        while (length > 1){
            System.out.print((length - 1) + " ");
            xMethod(length-1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        xMethod(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `length` never changes

Comment: What makes you think it *should* terminate? Why are you using loop in the first place along with recursion? Maybe instead of `while` you meant `if`?

Comment: It was an exam question. I thought it terminated, but it does not. Like I can't seem to wrap my head around it solely because just now, I changed my code for length > 0, and it just got stuck at xMethod(1) and never reaches xMethod(0), and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Because `length` is never updated.

```
while (length > 1){
   System.out.print((length - 1) + " ");
   xMethod(length - 1);
   length--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! But like when they have xMethod(length-1), doesn't that change the next input value from 5 to 4? Like it goes 5, 4, 3, 2, and then 1? Just because its calling xMethod for length-1? Thanks so much!

Comment: `length - 1` doesn't change `length` value, `length--` does. Also note that `The only difference is that the prefix version (--length) evaluates to the incremented value, whereas the postfix version (length--) evaluates to the original value`

Comment: @DaanyalAkhtar Each method call reserves some portion of stack memory for its local variables (which includes method parameters). When you call `xMethod(5)` it sets `5` to its `int length` parameter, but later when you are calling `xMethod(length-1)` `length-1` is calculated to `4` so it is like invoking `xMethod(4)` and that `4` is set to `int length` of that *separate* method (in different part of stack). In other words `xMethod(length-1)` doesn't change `length` of *current* method which means `while(length>1)` will always be based on `length` which is `5` and always evaluate it to `true`.

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks so much! So then my question is, I'm trying to trace this, and I am still kind of clueless as to why at xMethod(2) it is able to print 1, and why then it is not able to call xMethod(1)? Because according to my understanding, if xMethod(1) is called, it will be terminated because 1 is not greater than 1. Why, if the while loop is able to invoke xMethod(4), xMethod(3), and xMethod(2), what stops it from invoking xMethod(1)? Thanks so much! So sorry about the several questions!

Comment: @DaanyalAkhtar "*Why, if the while loop is able to invoke xMethod(4), xMethod(3), and xMethod(2), what stops it from invoking xMethod(1)*" you already answered it earlier, `xMethod(1)` **is** invoked, but since its `length` is 1 `while (length > 1){..}` doesn't iterate even once so it also doesn't `print((length - 1) + " ")` (otherwise it would print 0 and call `xMethod(0)`). After that `xMethod(2)` loops again, and after printing result of `2-1` it again calls `xMethod(1)` which again doesn't do anything and returns control flow to `xMethod(2)` and cycle repeats (printing 1 infinitely).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks so much! I wrote the same code in Python, and I was able to visualize its execution. My question is therefore, since xMethod(1) will terminate the program, I still can't wrap my head around how and why the program "goes back" to xMethod(2)? Thanks so much, and so sorry that I keep asking follow-up questions.

Comment: @DaanyalAkhtar `xMethod(1)` will not terminate the program, it will return control flow to method which *invoked* it - here `xMethod(2)`. That is expected behavior, just like when you call `System.out.println("something")` in main method you don't expect your program to finish, but to pass control flow back to `main` method, which lets it execute some other instructions after it. Without it we wouldn't be able to call more than one method inside other methods.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer have point it out, you need to decrements the `length` variable to fix your current problem with `length = length - 1` or `length--`. (I let my "colleague" answer to explain it better).

---

My answer is mostly about you usage of a recursive method.

What you probably want is simple an `if` condition. The recursion will act as loop.

```
public static void xMethod(int length) {
    length--;
    System.out.print((length) + " ");
    if (length > 1){
        xMethod(length);
    }
}
```

> xMethod(5) > 4 3 2 1

```
public static void xMethod(int length) {
    length--;
    if (length > 1){
        xMethod(length);
    }
    System.out.print((length) + " ");
}
```

> xMethod(5) > 1 2 3 4

Answer (score 0):

Length is not changing at all

```
class Test {
public static void xMethod(int length) {
    while (length > 1){
        System.out.print((length - 1) + " ");
        xMethod(length-1);
        //need to change the length here
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    xMethod(5);
}
```

Comment: Compared to the other answers already given not sure this adds any value.

Comment: @Popeye but it is not worse than other answers which ware posted *at the same time* so I am not sure why your comment is directed *only* to this answer.

Comment: @Pshemo I'm not saying it's wrong (This is why I haven't downvoted), however there were other answers first that provided a better response.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to add here is to understand how the assignments work in Java.

The value of `length` is not changed because when you pass a value in the method and it goes in the `while` loop, the loop stops when the condition stops but not the recursion `xMethod(length-1);` you have used. That's why even if you add `length--` it will not print what you desire.

So for the program to work properly, you have to

1. Assign value to `length` variable
2. Change or remove the recursion.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

And once you go through the link, you will understand the **why the value is not changing**.

**Note:** From the link you come to know that `length--` is equal to `length = length -1`, so basically we have to assign the updated value to `length` variable.

Comment: Please see [answer] about links

Comment: Answers should be able to stay on their own even if links will break. Links should be used as source of optional *additional* information, not core of the answer. Please see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231), [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370).

Comment: @AxelH/Pshemo Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

length is always have the value 5. you should replace length-1 by length--.

```
class Test {
    public static void xMethod(int length) {
        while (length > 1){
            System.out.print((length--) + " ");
            xMethod(length);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        xMethod(5);
    }
}
```